# Defining extra stylesheets on a per-module basis in Symfony

Tags: php, css, symfony1

I've created a module called "home" in Symfony.

I want css used by elements found only within this module to be in a separate home.css file.

I've created the file `apps/frontend/modules/home/config/view.yml` and placed inside it:

```
default:
    stylesheets: [home.css]
```

`apps/frontend/config/view.yml` contains the line:

```
stylesheets:    [reset.css, main.css]
```

I was expecting loading the page `/home` to result in reset.css, main.css and home.css being loaded in that order. However, it loads main.css and then home.css, ignoring reset.css and not placing the files in the desired order.

Am I doing something wrong here? I am new to Symfony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must ad "all:" in your view.yml

```
all:
  stylesheets:    [reset.css, main.css]
```

for the order of the stylesheets, you could work with "-". If you want that reset and main are loaded before try stylesheets:    [-reset.css, -main.css]